# Timeout logging into chat

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, chat

Is anyone else unable to log into chat rooms today?

Other parts of the site seem to be working fine but trying to enter chat room listing invariably results in timeout.

Comment: We're currently investigating it.

Comment: I had some connectivity issues either yesterday or monday as well @Taryn, might be related. Posting messages then timed out for a while. Having to retry a couple of times before they got through.

Comment: `Is anyone else unable to log into chat rooms today?` — unfortunately yes. SmokeDetector can't.

Comment: Took me a couple of tries to get a connection with the chat server, yea.

Comment: Smokey having problems too, probably related. (He can login, but e.g. now having two in Tavern.)

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard Should be fixed now, a standby instance got a failover.

Comment: @Mast not really, Smokey is now dead. (At least in Tavern)

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard It is alive in Charcoal but having some problems (

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We had a problem with our ISP in New York data center that impacted several services, including chat.

Things are back online now, and we shouldn't have any further issues.